# Ошибка модуля keyboard (exit code 3221226356)

Tags: python, pyqt5, словари, qt-designer, python-keyboard

Пытаюсь создать клавиатуру используя модуль *keyboard* и *PyQt5*, но столкнулся с неявной ошибкой:\

- В случайное время не работает изменение фона или счёт нажатий клавиш;\
- Иногда вылезает ошибка ***"`exit code 3221226356`"***, чаще, когда "люто фигачу по клавишам";\
- Другие ошибки в интерпритаторе не выходят, будто сам код запрещает мне пользоваться функциеями или где-то застревает.

Немного почесав голову и интернет я подумал что дело в асинхронном, паралельном или конкурентном как-то там самого модуля, т.к. эта ошибка связана с использованием программой памяти.

Снова к вопросу: мне стоит избавится от *keyboard* и испробовать другой модуль?

[Сам код](https://github.com/Termot/keyboard/blob/main/main.py):

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
   def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
       *всякое для UI*

       self.keys_name()
       self.keyboard_activate()


   def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
       *всякое для UI*


   def keyboard_activate(self):
       keyboard.hook(self.print_pressed_keys)


   # при нажатии клавиши прибавляем единицу к счету нажатия
   def click_up(self, btn, smvls_dict):
       if btn in smvls_dict:
           smvls_dict[btn] += 1
           self.scr_name[btn].setText(str(smvls_dict[btn]))

   
   # меняем фон клавиш при их нажатии
   def background(self, type, name):
       btn_name = self.btn_name[name]

       if type == 'on':
           btn_name.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(186, 186, 186);")
       if type == 'off':
           btn_name.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(240, 240, 240);")


   def ru2en(self, btn):
       simvols_ru = ['ё','й','ц','у','к','е','н','г','ш','щ','з','х','ъ',
                     'ф','ы','в','а','п','р','о','л','д','ж','э',
                     'я','ч','с','м','и','т','ь','б','ю', '.']

       simvols_en = ['`','q','w','e','r','t','y','u','i','o','p','[',']',
                     'a','s','d','f','g','h','j','k','l',';',"'",
                     'z','x','c','v','b','n','m',',','.', '/']

       # пеоеводим символы русской клавиатуры в символы английской
       if btn in simvols_ru:
           btn = simvols_en[simvols_ru.index(btn)]

       return btn


   def print_pressed_keys(self, e):
       if e.event_type == 'down':
           # превращаем в строку
           # переводим в нижний регистр
           # меняем русскую раскладку на английскую
           btn = self.ru2en((str(e.name)).lower())
           self.background('on', btn)

       if e.event_type == 'up':
           btn = self.ru2en((str(e.name)).lower())
           self.background('off', btn)

           smvls_dict = self.smvls_dict

           if btn in smvls_dict:
               print('btn', btn)
               print('e.name', e.name)
               self.click_up(btn, smvls_dict)


   # функция содержит в себе словари
   # 1. счета нажатых клавиш (letters_dict, smvls_dict)
   # 2. имена переменных соответствующие нажатым клавишам получаемых с e.name (btn_name, scr_nameм)
   def keys_name(self):
       # словарь счета нажатых букв
       *много переменных в словарях*


if __name__ == "__main__":
   import sys
   import keyboard

   btn_clicks = {}
   app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
   MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
   ui = Ui_MainWindow()
   ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
   MainWindow.show()
   sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Позволю себе дать вам некоторые советы:

1. Чтобы получать реальную ошибку, ВСЕГДА запускайте свое приложение в CMD/консоли/терминале.
2. НИКОГДА НЕ ИЗМЕНЯЙТЕ код, сгенерированный Qt Designer, НИКОГДА. 
   Создайте другой класс, который наследуется от соответствующего виджета, и используйте созданный класс для его заполнения.

---

Я не проверял вашу логику, а только обработал ошибку. 
По сути я заменил строку:

```
    btn_name = self.btn_name[name]
```

на:

```
    btn_name = self.btn_name.get(name)                            # !!! +++
    if btn_name is None:                                          # !!! +++
        print(f'btn_name = {btn_name} ??????????????? ') #
        print('''Внимание 
            Что-то пошло не так. Проверьте "self.btn_name = {...}"
        ''') 
        return
```

Проверьте.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(813, 323)
    ...

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.btn_w.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "W"))
        ...
        self.scr_ralt.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "0"))
        self.scr_rctrl.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "0"))


# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

    def keyboard_activate(self):
        keyboard.hook(self.print_pressed_keys)

    # при нажатии клавиши прибавляем единицу к счету нажатия
    def click_up(self, btn, smvls_dict):
        if btn in smvls_dict:
            smvls_dict[btn] += 1
            self.scr_name[btn].setText(str(smvls_dict[btn]))
    
    # меняем фон клавиш при их нажатии
    def background(self, type, name):
        print(f'type = {type}') #
        print(f'name = {name}') #

# !!! +++
#        btn_name = self.btn_name[name]
        btn_name = self.btn_name.get(name)                            # !!! +++
        if btn_name is None:                                          # !!! +++
            print(f'btn_name = {btn_name} ??????????????? ') #
            print('''Внимание 
                Что-то пошло не так. Проверьте "self.btn_name = {...}"
            ''') 
            return
        print(f'btn_name = {btn_name.text()} ++++++++++++ ') #

        if type == 'on':
            btn_name.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(186, 186, 186);")
        if type == 'off':
            btn_name.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(240, 240, 240);")

    def ru2en(self, btn):
        simvols_ru = ['ё','й','ц','у','к','е','н','г','ш','щ','з','х','ъ',
                      'ф','ы','в','а','п','р','о','л','д','ж','э',
                      'я','ч','с','м','и','т','ь','б','ю', '.']

        simvols_en = ['`','q','w','e','r','t','y','u','i','o','p','[',']',
                      'a','s','d','f','g','h','j','k','l',';',"'",
                      'z','x','c','v','b','n','m',',','.', '/']

        # пеоеводим символы русской клавиатуры в символы английской
        if btn in simvols_ru:
            btn = simvols_en[simvols_ru.index(btn)]
        return btn

    def print_pressed_keys(self, e):
        if e.event_type == 'down':
            # превращаем в строку
            # переводим в нижний регистр
            # меняем русскую раскладку на английскую
            btn = self.ru2en((str(e.name)).lower())
            self.background('on', btn)

        if e.event_type == 'up':
            btn = self.ru2en((str(e.name)).lower())
            
            print(f'\ndef print_pressed_keys(self, e): btn = {btn} ???????????? \n') #
            self.background('off', btn)

            smvls_dict = self.smvls_dict

            if btn in smvls_dict:
                print('btn', btn)
                print('e.name', e.name)
                self.click_up(btn, smvls_dict)


    # функция содержит в себе словари
    # 1. счета нажатых клавиш (letters_dict, smvls_dict)
    # 2. имена переменных соответствующие нажатым клавишам 
    #    получаемых с e.name (btn_name, scr_nameм)
    def keys_name(self):
        # словарь счета нажатых букв
        self.letters_dict = {'q': 0, 'w': 0, 'e': 0, 'r': 0, 't': 0, 'y': 0, 'u': 0, 'i': 0, 'o': 0, 'p': 0,
                             'a': 0, 's': 0, 'd': 0, 'f': 0, 'g': 0, 'h': 0, 'j': 0, 'k': 0, 'l': 0,
                             'z': 0, 'x': 0, 'c': 0, 'v': 0, 'b': 0, 'n': 0, 'm': 0}

        # словарь счета нажатых символов и спец клавиш
        self.smvls_dict = {'q': 0, 'w': 0, 'e': 0, 'r': 0, 't': 0, 'y': 0, 'u': 0, 'i': 0, 'o': 0, 'p': 0,
                           'a': 0, 's': 0, 'd': 0, 'f': 0, 'g': 0, 'h': 0, 'j': 0, 'k': 0, 'l': 0,
                           'z': 0, 'x': 0, 'c': 0, 'v': 0, 'b': 0, 'n': 0, 'm': 0,
                           '+': 0, '*': 0, '-': 0, '-': 0, '=': 0,
                           '`': 0, '1': 0, '2': 0, '3': 0, '4': 0, '5': 0, '6': 0, '7': 0, '8': 0, '9': 0, '0': 0,
                           ',': 0, '.': 0, '/': 0, ';': 0, "'": 0, '[': 0, ']': 0, 
                           'tab': 0, 'caps lock': 0, 'shift': 0, 'ctrl': 0, 'alt': 0, 'space': 0, 'enter': 0,
                           'right alt': 0, 'right ctrl': 0, 'right shift': 0, 'left windows': 0,
                           'right': 0, 'left': 0, 'up': 0, 'down': 0,
                           'num lock': 0, 'insert': 0, 'end': 0, 'home': 0, 'page down': 0, 'page up': 0, 'clear': 0}

        # имена переменных букв (клавиш на клавиатуре)
        self.btn_name = {
            'q': self.btn_q, 'w': self.btn_w, 'e': self.btn_e, 
            'r': self.btn_r, 't': self.btn_t, 
            'y': self.btn_y, 'u': self.btn_u, 'i': self.btn_i, 'o': self.btn_o, 'p': self.btn_p, 
            'a': self.btn_a, 's': self.btn_s, 'd': self.btn_d, 'f': self.btn_f, 'g': self.btn_g, 
            'h': self.btn_h, 'j': self.btn_j, 'k': self.btn_k, 'l': self.btn_l, 
            'z': self.btn_z, 'x': self.btn_x, 'c': self.btn_c, 'v': self.btn_v, 'b': self.btn_b, 
            'n': self.btn_n, 'm': self.btn_m,

            '[':self.btn_op_scq_br, ']': self.btn_cl_sqr_br, ';': self.btn_semicolon, 
            "'":self.btn_apstf, ',': self.btn_comma, '.': self.btn_dot, '/': self.btn_f_slash, 

            '`': self.btn_tilde, '-': self.btn_minus, '=': self.btn_equal,
            '1': self.btn_1, '2': self.btn_2, '3': self.btn_3, '4': self.btn_4, '5': self.btn_5, 
            '6': self.btn_6, '7': self.btn_7, '8': self.btn_8, '9': self.btn_9, '0': self.btn_0,

            'tab': self.btn_tab, 'caps lock': self.btn_capslock, 'shift': self.btn_shift, 
            'ctrl': self.btn_ctrl, 'alt': self.btn_alt, 'space': self.btn_space,
            'left windows': self.btn_win, 'right alt': self.btn_ralt, 'right ctrl': self.btn_rctrl}

        # имена переменных счета (циферки под бувами)
        self.scr_name = {'q': self.scr_q, 'w': self.scr_w, 'e': self.scr_e, 'r': self.scr_r, 't': self.scr_t,
                         'y': self.scr_y, 'u': self.scr_u, 'i': self.scr_i, 'o': self.scr_o, 'p': self.scr_p,
                         'a': self.scr_a, 's': self.scr_s, 'd': self.scr_d, 'f': self.scr_f, 'g': self.scr_g,
                         'h': self.scr_h, 'j': self.scr_j, 'k': self.scr_k, 'l': self.scr_l,
                         'z': self.scr_z, 'x': self.scr_x, 'c': self.scr_c, 'v': self.scr_v, 'b': self.scr_b,
                         'n': self.scr_n, 'm': self.scr_m,

                         '[': self.scr_op_scq_b, ']': self.scr_cl_sqr_br, ';': self.scr_semicolon,
                         "'": self.scr_apstrf, ',': self.scr_comma, '.': self.scr_dot, '/': self.scr_f_slash,

                         '`': self.scr_tilde, '-': self.scr_minus, '=': self.scr_ecuals,
                         '1': self.scr_n_1, '2': self.scr_n_2, '3': self.scr_n_3, '4': self.scr_n_4, '5': self.scr_n_5,
                         '6': self.scr_n_6, '7': self.scr_n_7, '8': self.scr_n_8, '9': self.scr_n_9, '0': self.scr_n_0,

                         'tab': self.scr_tab, 'caps lock': self.scr_capslock, 'shift': self.scr_shift,
                         'ctrl': self.scr_ctrl, 'alt': self.scr_alt, 'space': self.scr_space,
                         'left windows': self.scr_win, 'right alt': self.scr_ralt, 'right ctrl': self.scr_rctrl}


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    import keyboard
    import asyncio

# ???    btn_clicks = {}
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    
#    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
#    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
#    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
#    MainWindow.show()
 
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
     
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, как минимум я понял как лучше оформлять дебаг и что, на мое удивление, лучше отслеживать ошибки через CMD, а так же напоминание про класс Qt'шника. За метод get() тоже огромное спасибо.

Comment: @Termot пожалуйста.  Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, 
как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Пометил. Хотел еще получить помощь по другому вопросу из шапки: почему не меняется фон? У меня нет идей как исправить это или найти ответ в интернете. (случается это из-за одновременного нажатия множества клавиш)

Comment: @Termot в одном посте принято задавать ОДИН вопрос. Если у вас есть другие проблемы - задайте новый вопрос. Приведите пример кода, который демонстрирует проблему. Хорошо распишите какие надо делать действия чтобы получить проблему, о которой вы будете спрашивать.